# Android fast app rotation crash

Tags: android, rotation, screen

When i am logged in android application, and fast rotating screen, app can't handle onSaveInstanceState and onCreate(loading user and performing login). So i get logged out. Can i somehow handle rotations, and not allowing to call those methods so quick?

Comment: If the app is implemented correctly, the problem is definitely not the speed. Do you have any threads, asynctasks or such? Is it your app?

Comment: I'm with @ClassStacker here, your problem is not the speed -- rotations happen sequentally, so no matter how fast you do it, they won't overlap and cause mayhem by themselves. Something else is wrong

Comment: If you're using AsyncTask, check this article http://blogactivity.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/proper-use-of-asynctask/ you may be falling out of sync with the current instance of your activity

Answer (score 0):

When you rotates the device your Activity will re-create and all the variables will be re-initialized. So, in that case if you want to some values to remain same on Rotation also you can store their state using the onSaveInstanceState() and you can restore in onCreate() again by checking Bundle is not null.

```
if(savedInstanceState != null){
            // get the restore value from the Bundle
        }
```

Where as onConfigurationChanged() will be called when you rotate the Device(Note that this will only be called if you have selected configurations you would like to handle with the
This method is called when screen rotated

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        //Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: This is simply not true in itself. Please refine your answer.

Comment: Problem is that if you rotate slow, everything is ok. So onCreate gets non-null bundle, i get login, everything is ok. But on fast change of rotation, look it can't handle quick enought, and let say user data gets lost.

Comment: Once again, @bostek, it has nothing to do with the speed _if_ your code is implemented correctly, because the order in which the callbacks are called is well-defined. What _does_ cause trouble could be: AsyncTasks which do not finish quickly enough, event handlers holding references to destroyed UI objects, _AND_ wrongly located code (accessing UI element choice in onCreate when the UI is not yet initialized, asymmetric startup and shutdown of animations and business logic, etc)

Comment: Thank you for refining your answer. I will still insist that the best practice to store data for a configuration change is through `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`, because this way, it will simply be held in memory as a reference, while in the case of the saved instance state, overhead is higher. But I'm aware that many people ignore this fact and device manufacturers are throwing quad-core processors in the ring. ;)

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn Please excuse me, I clicked wrongly... I can't undo my downvote now unless you edit again, sorry... not sure how this happened.

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn Undid my downvote. Will not upvote, because the OP is currently handling orientation changes "the real Android way" and maybe he has to/wants to. Your proposition might have severe implications for his code; we don't know (yet).